# SQL Foreign key for Primary key with 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

As far as I'm aware, you can only assign primary keys and unique columns to foreign keys... yet I have a table that has a primary key between two columns:

```
alter table NAME add constraint PK primary key(VALUE1, VALUE2)
```

I'm trying to make Value1 a foreign key in another table, but it's not recognizing it as a primary key or unique - obviously because the primary key is shared between two values... So what do I do from here? I'm pretty new to SQL syntax...

Comment: 1: Foreign keys do not have to be unique. 2: Foreign keys can consist of multiple columns like primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can only assign primary keys and unique columns to foreign keys. I am not much aware of the business requirement here but ideally, you should be having a third table which has the VALUE1 as a primary key. If not you should create one.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that you can't link a foreign key to a value that can hold duplicates on the referenced table. So if your main table has a compound key (more than 1 column), linking the foreign key to one (or many but not all) of it's columns would be linking the table to more than one row (since that column might have duplicates by itself).

If you really need to establish the link between the two then you have a problem, either:

- Your primary key isn't really 2 or more columns. You can read about normalizing your database (in standard normal forms) to solve this.
- Your relationship between the tables isn't 1 to N (it's N to M). You can't add a foreign key, you will have to create a 3rd table with both primary keys to link them.